# Payoneer integration in laravel

Tags: laravel, api

Need of Payoneer integration in my project. I am beginner in Laravel and could not understand how to integrate Payoneer REST API it in my project?

Comment: maybe try this one
https://github.com/viralstyle/laravel-payoneer

Answer (score 1):

get payoneer sandbox credentials from payoneer authorities.
Then Login to https://partners.sandbox.payoneer.com
Go to developer section and there having basic API call for each language.